# Inserting a date and time of execution of a bash script into a file

Tags: bash

I need to figure out how to automatically insert a date and time of execution of a certain bash script file, into a txt file. Lets just say I have a bash script named backup.sh, and each time backup.sh executes, it would automatically create a txt file named Execution.txt, and within that txt file, the date and time of the execution of backup.sh would be written there. Does anyone have ideas to do this? I have Googled for some answers, but found nothing. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put this inside your `backup.sh` file:

```
date > Execution.txt
```

This will *create* the file `Execution.txt` inside the current working directory. The file will contain the current date and time (if it already exists, it will be overwritten). Of course you may specify an absolute path to the file:

```
date > /absolute/path/to/Execution.txt
```

To *append* to the file (instead of overwriting it), use `>>` instead of `>`, i.e.,

```
date >> Execution.txt
```

Comment: I recommend against using absolute paths to commands. It is not more secure. setuid bit on scripts doesn't work. It is disabled.

Comment: @geirha Actually I just thought of this myself; you are perfectly right. As far as Linux is concerned at least. On MacOS X for instance, things are different (setuid may be enabled for scripts). Yet, an absolute path does not make the script less secure either. And it still ensures that the intended command is indeed executed, even when the `PATH` is weird. Do you actually have any arguments why using an absolute path may be *bad*?

Comment: It makes the script harder to maintain. What if command `foo` is at `/bin/foo` on one system, but `/usr/bin/foo` at another? you'd have to go through the entire script changing it from one to the other. If you don't know what `PATH` is set to, set it yourself at the start of the script.

Comment: Hm, ok, fine. I guess you have a point. I reverted my last edit. Cheers and thanks for the comment. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to record the date for one event in a script, it's likely you'll want to keep a running log.  The `date` command can be pressed into service as a simple event logger:

```
date +'%c|Backup started' >> backup.log
```

The `+` option allows you to format the date anyway you chose. The details of date formatting are explained in [`man date`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/date.1posix.html). The above command will append a line to the log that looks something like:

```
Tue Mar 25 14:49:28 2014|Backup started
```

The pipe separator makes parsing the log a bit easier if you add different events:

```
date +"%c|Backup completed: $?" >> backup.log
```

`$?` is the return status of the last command to be executed, but you can use any variable that might be helpful for debugging later. (Note: you need to use double quotes if you want variables to be interpolated.) Looking at the log, you'd be able to discover a possible failure:

```
Tue Mar 25 14:49:28 2014|Backup started
Tue Mar 25 14:49:52 2014|Backup completed: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the following line in your `backup.sh` script:

```
date >> /path/to/Execution.txt
```

Explanation:

- `date` - print the system date and time
- `>> /path/to/Execution.txt` redirect the output and appends it to the `/path/toExecution.txt` file.